# how to use map function in react native. undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.route.params.data.map...')

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have sent data from first screen to second screen by Params. in first screen I get data from API server. Now I want to show that data in second screen. I have multiple data so I want to show only once and then after . for example 100 data will come then 100  card  should create automatically.

but now I am getting error like this => undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.route.params.data.map...')

here is my code

```
    <View>
        //  {/*Use map on data as you want to show*/}
         {this.props.route.params.data.map(item => 
            <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center",height:140, width:"90%", marginTop:30}}>
               
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}>
                <Card center middle shadow style={{ height:80, width:"100%" }} >

                {/*Use item*/}

                <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:190}}>  
                {item} 
                </Text>
            
                  </Card>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                 </View>
           )}
          </View>
```

Comment: 1. Make sure that the data gets fulfilled. 2. If the the data gets fulfilled, just protect your map (`this.props.route.params && this.props.route.params.data && this.props.route.params.data.map...`) (or use optional chaining)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you have to write your code like this :

```
   {this.props.route.params && this.props.route.params.data && 
   this.props.route.params.data.map((item,index) => {
   return(
   <View></View>
   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **optional chaining** to check whether the data is in **route.params** or not.

***Complete code:***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
    
    export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
        const data = this.props?.route?.params?.data;
        return (
          <View>
            {data &&
              data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      height: 140,
                      width: "90%",
                      marginTop: 30,
                    }}
                  >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}
                    >
                      <Card
                        center
                        middle
                        shadow
                        style={{ height: 80, width: "100%" }}
                      >
                        {/*Use item*/}
    
                        <Text
                          medium
                          height={15}
                          size={14}
                          style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight: 190 }}
                        >
                          {item}
                        </Text>
                      </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```